# How to avoid dark/black area in blender when using hemi?

Tags: light

I use blender to render patent images, which require "black and white" drawings. Hemi is very handy because 1 hemi lamp is enough and no shadows. But this time I got this:
[image]
After using gimp Edge detect -> Revert colors -> Auto-crop image -> Threshold to 239 -> 1 bit color index, I got this:
[image]
It's still usable, but it's ugly! So what happened? Hemi lamp used to be simple and works great! All I need is to put 1 single hemi lamp at origin (0,0,0)!

After I set 0.01 thickness(using extrude/z/.01) to those "black planes", they're all dark/black now...
[image]

It seems to have something to do with camera direction. There would be no dark/black planes if you looked from downside of the planes, just like this:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

There is no edges showing on the planes because they have no thickness. Add a slight thickness to each plane and you should see detectable edges.

This seems an odd way of doing this though, I'd look into blender's [edge detection functionality](https://docs.blender.org/manual/ko/dev/render/blender_render/post_processing/edges.html) or [freestyle](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/freestyle/index.html) as an alternative.

Comment: Yep, sounds like a highly inefficient and inaccurate way of doing this, even a viewport capture might be faster.

Comment: Sure. I had tried them both. Blender's Edge Detect can only detect some of all edges —— even 80% would be confused. Freestyle is the opposite —— sometimes it renders more edges than needed. I was using Freestyle all along and forgot to mentioned it. Those steps are merely to remove colors and keep only the edge lines.

Comment: It didn't work... I post the result in the original post because I can not post pictures here in the comment.

Comment: @jondoe interesting, I'll take a more detailed look when I get a chance. I still think that this should be doable with just freestyle.

Comment: It seems to have something to do with camera direction. There would be no dark/black planes if you looked from downside of the planes. Any ideas?

Comment: USPTO says they only accept "Black & White lines drawings", but I've seen some 3D rendering drawings, with grayscale other than black and white. I'll just follow their claim, they did put me to file a data sheet 8 time repeatedly, in 2 months, just because I signed my name xx li as li xx...